# Spark Notebook: How can I filter rows based on a column value where each column cell is an array of strings?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge dataframe where a column "categories" has various attributes of a business i.e. whether it's a Restaurant, Laundry Service, Disco Theque etc. What I need is to be able to `.filter` the dataframe such that each row which contains Restaurant may be seen. The problem here is that "categories" is an array of strings where a cell may be like: "Restaurants, Food, Nightlife". Any ideas? (Scala [2.10.6] Spark [2.0.1] Hadoop [2.7.2])

I have tried SQL style queries like:

```
val countResult = sqlContext.sql(
   "SELECT business.neighborhood, business.state, business.stars, business.categories 
    FROM business where business.categories == Restaurants group by business.state"
).collect() 
display(countResult)
```

and

```
dfBusiness.filter($"categories" == "Restaurants").show()
```

and

```
dfBusiness.filter($"categories" == ["Restaurants"]).show()
```

I think I might need to iterate over each cell but I have no idea on how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a good start. I think you should add that to your question and the version of Spark you are using. It is always good to be as complete and specific as possible. Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [functions library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) can be very helpful for processing columns in a `DataFrame`. In this case, `array_contains` should provide what you need:

```
dfBusiness.filter(array_contains($"categories", "Restaurants"))
```

This filters out any rows that don't have a "*Restaurants*" element in the array in the `categories` column.